# JButton can't be resolved inside actionListener

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to make a simple GUI calculator with Eclipse
The actionlistener is at the bottom, and eclipse says my ButtonAdd can't be resolved
the error is around lines 125-131, Any help is appreciated! :D

```
package main;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GUIApp {

private JFrame frame;
public JTextField txtNumber_1;
public JTextField txtNumber;
public JTextField textField;
public JButton ButtonAdd;
public JButton ButtonSub;
public JButton ButtonMulti;
public JButton ButtonDiv;
public JButton btnRng;
String num1;
String num2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                GUIApp window = new GUIApp();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public GUIApp() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * @return 
 */
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    ButtonAdd = new JButton("Addition");
    ButtonAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            num1 = txtNumber_1.getText();
            num2 = txtNumber.getText();
           if(ButtonAdd.getModel().isPressed())
            textField.setText(num1 + num2);
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_ButtonAdd = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_ButtonAdd.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_ButtonAdd.gridx = 0;
    gbc_ButtonAdd.gridy = 0;
    frame.getContentPane().add(ButtonAdd, gbc_ButtonAdd);

    ButtonSub = new JButton("Subtraction");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_ButtonSub = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_ButtonSub.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_ButtonSub.gridx = 0;
    gbc_ButtonSub.gridy = 2;
    frame.getContentPane().add(ButtonSub, gbc_ButtonSub);

    txtNumber_1 = new JTextField();
    txtNumber_1.setText("Number 1");
    txtNumber_1.setToolTipText("insert a number");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtNumber_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtNumber_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_txtNumber_1.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtNumber_1.gridx = 3;
    gbc_txtNumber_1.gridy = 2;
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtNumber_1, gbc_txtNumber_1);
    txtNumber_1.setColumns(10);

    ButtonMulti = new JButton("Multiplication");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_ButtonMulti = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_ButtonMulti.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_ButtonMulti.gridx = 0;
    gbc_ButtonMulti.gridy = 4;
    frame.getContentPane().add(ButtonMulti, gbc_ButtonMulti);

    txtNumber = new JTextField();
    txtNumber.setText("Number 2");
    txtNumber.setToolTipText("insert other number");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_txtNumber = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_txtNumber.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_txtNumber.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_txtNumber.gridx = 3;
    gbc_txtNumber.gridy = 5;
    frame.getContentPane().add(txtNumber, gbc_txtNumber);
    txtNumber.setColumns(10);

    ButtonDiv = new JButton("Division");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_ButtonDiv = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_ButtonDiv.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
    gbc_ButtonDiv.gridx = 0;
    gbc_ButtonDiv.gridy = 6;
    frame.getContentPane().add(ButtonDiv, gbc_ButtonDiv);

    btnRng = new JButton("RNG");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnRng = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnRng.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
    gbc_btnRng.gridx = 0;
    gbc_btnRng.gridy = 8;
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnRng, gbc_btnRng);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setToolTipText("output");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.gridx = 3;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 8;
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc_textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String num1;
    String num2;
    num1 = txtNumber_1.getText();
    num2 = txtNumber.getText();
   if(ButtonAdd.getModel().isPressed())
    textField.setText(num1 + num2);

}
}
```

The GUI was made with WindowBuilder by the way

Comment: Your `ButtonAdd` 's scope is limited to the `initialize` method.

Comment: (1-) `the error is around lines 125-131,` - what do you mean "around"??? The error message will tell you "exactly" the line causing the problem. If you want help then be explicit with your questions. We don't have time to question what line may or may not be causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ButtonAdd` is a local reference, meaning it can only be accessed inside the `initialize` method. A solution to this is to declare the `ButtonAdd` outside the method.

```
JButton ButtonAdd;

public void initialize() {
   ButtonAdd = new JButton("Addition");
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
   // here we can now access ButtonAdd
}
```

Also a tip, by java's standard naming conventions you usually start variables and references with a lower case letter, so `ButtonAdd` -> `buttonAdd`

Comment: thanks! That removed the error but the button won't change the text in the output box

Comment: When i double clicked it, it just took me to where i built the button

Comment: the textfield still wont change

Comment: now instead of adding the numbers together, it just puts them together like if i put 1 and 2 it will say 12

Answer (score 1):

because it is not a member variable. make it one and it works

`JButton ButtonAdd = new JButton("Addition");` is inside another method therefore it is not visible to your action listener